# Error with Dynamics AX Web Service 'DateTimeConverter cannot convert from Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.AxShared.utcdatetime'

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm attempting to test a web service I've built based on a class I created in AX. The class only has one method call in which I have hard coded all the values for, for the time being, just to make sure things work. One of the parameters the method requires is a utcdatetime which I believe is somehow causing the error "DateTimeConverter cannot convert from Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.AxShared.utcdatetime". I'm using Visual Studio to call the Web Service I've created, a very simple console application for test purposes. Does anyone have any insight on this error and how to fix this? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here's a sample of what the code looks like. I've tried many different ways of creating the utcdatetime but no luck.

```
[SysEntryPointAttribute(true)]
public str TestMethod()
{
    System.DateTime netDttm;
    utcDateTime xppDate;
    //str strTemp;

    xppDate = 2016-07-29T12:00:00;
    netDttm = Global::utcDateTime2SystemDateTime(xppDate);

    results = OtherClass::MethodCall("string", netDttm);
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you take a look at [How to: Convert Between utcdatetime and System.DateTime - AX 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc553823.aspx)?

Comment: I've seen that and attempted to use it but I'm not sure this applies here. I'm not sure I was clear in my question. The date property is declared and set in the class built in AX. I'm not passing anything in the web service call. Everything is hard coded inside the method.

The method itself is calling another method from an outside class and requires a parameter of a utcdatetime. So my custom method that I'm calling looks like this:

public str TestMethod()
{
     otherclass::methodCall("string", utcdate);
     return "test";
}

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show us some of that hard coded values?

Comment: but I'm not getting any returned value just an error message which means it's erring out on the method call.

Comment: Could you tell us more about `OtherClass::MethodCall`? You write in your comment that it is an "outside" class, what does that mean? Is it just another x++ class or is it a class from a dll?